# Debian - Watch and compile less automatically

Tags: debian, less

I was wondering how I could watch `.less` files automatically and compile them. Without GUI.

As I'm developing with bootstrap on a live debian server, I really don't want to save the less file, go to PuTTY and type `lessc less/bootstrap.less > css/bootstrap.css` every time I make a change. I might as well use plain css if I have to do it like this every time.

So, I would have to watch **every** file with `.less` on directory /less/ and when a change is made, run `lessc less/bootstrap.less > css/bootstrap.css`. But how would I do it?

Yeah, I could use `cron` but it only offers once in a minute refresh. So it's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used [File Watcher](https://github.com/thomasfl/filewatcher) and [FSSM](https://github.com/ttilley/fssm) to do this, depending on the OS (and how keen I was to learn a new tool). The latter is probably the best for Linux, but is written in Ruby.

For a pure C-tool that would do what you want, I like inotifywait of [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki). The website has some nice examples and a package is available for Debian. If none of the tools do exactly whay you want, [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html) is an example of how to use the inotify API.

Comment: And how am I supposed to install FSSM? It completely lacks any installation guide.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the documentation is very bad. It is a ruby gem, so you install and use it like any other Ruby-library (i.e., gem install fssm). I see that in Ubuntu, there is always an fssm-package.